# TYPO3 and Remote synchronization toolkits

Tags: synchronization, typo3

I am looking for your suggestions on  which (free, open source)
tool/package I may use to keep two TYPO3 installs syncronized.

I see that treesync 
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/treesync has not been
updated for a long lapse of time.
Is it something people still use?

It does not need to be a TYPO3 BE module, a third party tool would be
fine too, if it could be configured for the task with TYPO3 easily 
(a nice GUI would help)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the content publisher of in2code:

https://contentpublisher.in2code.de/

Otherwise I only know of two other setups:
* Do it manually: rsync of files and transfer of a database dump
* setup of a mysql replication and the use of a synchronized filesystem like ocfs2

Best regards,
Marcus

Comment: No, I don't. Please ask directly. They are very helpful and polite.